# Text color doesn't change with overall theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

[Link to the themes change site](https://hritik-jaiswal.github.io/theme-changer/)

Whenever I try to change the theme of the page, the color of text doesn't change with it.
[Link to the files](https://github.com/Hritik-Jaiswal/theme-changer/)

Comment: can u add the code with which u are changes themes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to color for `<a>` instead of inherit.

```
a {
  color: var(--text) !important;
}
```

Comment: It was just a simple thing, thank you for telling me. But I don't get why "color: inherit;" was not working?

Comment: I don't know the direct reason for that, but one possible reason might be that one of its parent element might be causing issue by not getting the color of body this might be why adding variable color directly to the `<a>` would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

In sandbox file try this to add a class to body

```js
body.classList.add(theme)
```